# How do I fix this syntax error in my query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I keep hitting this error in SSMS:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '.11'.

My query:

```
UPDATE copia.server set ipaddress =192.168.11.34, isactive=1, isWebResourceServer=1, servername =TestCopia.JAR
WHERE serverkey=1
```

I originally copied and pasted the query but then I read where that could lead to problems. I typed it out manually and still the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to enclose strings (varchar/char) fields in single or double quotes:

```
UPDATE copia.server set ipaddress = '192.168.11.34', isactive=1, isWebResourceServer=1, servername = 'TestCopia.JAR'
WHERE serverkey=1
```